# I have a nested ul in my nav, why does it not show everything in the list for mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, navigationbar

For my main navigation I have a nested ul that is only displaying the first 6 li when Products is clicked. How do I get them all to display when the user clicks Products? Is it a CSS thing or a script problem? Here's a screenshot.

[image: Here's a picture of the mobile nav in action]

HTML:

```
    <nav>
        <a class="burger_nav"></a>
        <span id="logo_link">
            <a href="#"><img src="images/nav_logo.gif" alt="Company logo. Links to home page." width="100%"></a>
        </span>
        <ul>
        <span id="phonly"><li><a href="#">Home</a></li></span>
           <li><a class="sub_drop">Products</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Resilient Floor</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Wood Floor</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Food Service</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Dilution Control</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Carpet Care</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">General Cleaners</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Disinfectants</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Industrial</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Restroom Care</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Hand Care</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Laundry Care</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Green Products</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">International</a></li>
                </ul><!-- dropdown -->
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">SDS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Libraries</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

Script:

```
//// phone nav burger

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".burger_nav").on("click", function(){
            $("nav ul").toggleClass("open");
        });
    });

   //// phone nav products
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".sub_drop").on("click", function(){
            $("nav ul ul").toggleClass("open");
        });
    });
```

CSS:

```
/*********** NAVIGATION (full screen)************/
#phonly{
    display:none;
}

#logo_link{
    float:left;
    padding-top:9px;
    padding-top:0.47vw;
    width:128px;
    width:6.72vw;
    margin-left:3.9531%;
    margin-right:3.9531%;
}

nav{
    float:left;
    border-bottom:1px solid #BBB;
    z-index:4;

}

nav ul{
    list-style-type:none;
    text-align:left;    
}

nav ul li{
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    width:11.6399%;
    font-size:21px;
    font-size:1vw;
}

nav ul li:hover ul{
    left:0px;
    opacity:1;
}

nav ul li a{
    display:block;
    width:175px;
    padding:11px;
    padding:0.58vw;
    color:#000;
    background-color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
}

nav ul li a:hover{
    background-color:#003768;
    color:#fff;
}

nav ul li a:active{
    color:#F00;
}

nav ul ul{
    background-color:#999;
    opacity:0;
    position:absolute;
    left:-9999px;
    z-index:20;
}

nav ul ul li{
    float:none;
    color:#000;
}

nav ul ul li a:active{
    background-color:#000;
    color:#F00;
}

nav ul ul li a:visited{
    color:#003768;
}

nav ul ul li a:hover{
    background-color:#003768;
    color:#fff;
}


/************* MOBILE *********/
@media screen and (max-width:450px){

#logo_link{
    display:none;
}

#phonly{
    display:block;
}

.burger_nav{
    display:block;
    height:40px;
    width:100%;
    background:url(../images/burger.png) no-repeat 3% center;
    background-color:#404040;
    cursor:pointer;
}

nav{
    background-color:#fff;
    width:100%;
}

nav ul{
    list-style-type:none;
    text-align:left;
    overflow:hidden;
    height:0;   
}

nav ul.open{
    height:auto;
}

nav ul li{
    float:none;
    width:100%;
    font-size:21px;
}

nav ul li:hover ul{
    left:0px;
    opacity:1;
}

nav ul li a{
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    padding:11px;
    color:#000;
    background-color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #444;
}

nav ul ul.open{
    height:auto
}

nav ul ul{

    list-style-type:none;
    text-align:left;
    overflow:hidden;
    height:0;   
}

nav ul ul li{
    float:none;
    color:#000;
}

.sub_drop{
    cursor:pointer;
}

nav ul ul li a{
    white-space:nowrap;
    width:100vw;
    background-color:#fff;
    color:#000;
    font-size:16px;
}

nav ul ul li a:visited{
    color:#003768;
}

nav ul ul li a:hover{
    background-color:#003768;
    color:#fff;
}

}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Did I write something wrong in the style sheet? Is the script incorrect? It's not my HTML is it? Thank you for your time.

Comment: It'll be much easier if you upload somewhere your page, so we could debug it

Comment: Because you have overflow hidden on one of the parent `ul` and since your dropdown is absolute, it will not show once you paste the ul height

Comment: @ Huangism - OK so for the phone styles I tried position:static and position:relative. It kinda works, but when the page is refreshed there is a large blank area where the nested list goes. Once Products is clicked it all works and looks as it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've tried your code here: http://jsbin.com/zabimicati/edit?css,output
The issue in `overflow:hidden;` for `nav ul` in `@media screen and (max-width: 450px)`.
The easiest way to fix - remove it. But the question is how you expect it to work.
E.g. you may add after `overflow: hidden;` additionally `overflow-y: visible;`

Comment: To answer your question - I only want the nested ul to show when the user clicks Products. Then when they click it again I would like the nested ul to hide. What does overflow-y: visible; do?

Comment: `visible` is opposite to `hidden`. Currently your subnav list is cut-off by parent's `overflow: hidden;`. As you still have layout issue with dropdown nav (Products list goes little bit too far right), so you may still need to cut it horizontally (that's why you may need `overflow: hidden`), but we can remove cutting-off vertically (overflow-y)

Comment: Regarding opening on click. This doesn't work currently, I believe. It becomes visible only because of `nav ul li:hover ul{
    left:0px;
    opacity:1;
}`. You may try to add the same rules for `nav ul ul.open`

Comment: OK I added overflow-y:visible; to nav ul and I added those rules to nav ul ul.open and now both ul's show up when the burger is clicked. Is there any way to only show the nested ul when Products is clicked?

Comment: @theBartender could you create jsbin with your latest changes? I guess, something is not ok in logic (in css or js)

Comment: Sure. I just edited the one you made. [link](http://jsbin.com/bacorakaku/edit?css,output)

Comment: @theBartender try this http://jsbin.com/gijayikori/1/edit?js,output I your first click handler you were adding 'open' class to ALL 'ul' inside nav. also improved the second one, as it also was opeping any second level list

Comment: THANK YOU! That does it. Really well too.